# Windows C++ library for operations on mesh with a mex-interface in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, c++, mesh

Please recommend me a well documented C++ library that I could wrap with a mex-interface in Matlab.

The library should have the capability to read meshes (optimal in different formats, at least in AVS-UCD-format). To these meshes some operations should be applied:

Smoothing, subdivision, reduction, translations, scaling, and most important make a double layer shell from a one layer mesh for printing.

I'm a total naive in dealing with mesh, and I'm trying to learn.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it satisfies all requirements, but TriMesh is pretty easy to use:

http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/proj/trimesh2/

JMeshlib was also a common choice, but an old one:
http://jmeshlib.sourceforge.net/

---

Instead of pointer based arithmetic, MATLAB in general, uses a [Faces, Vertices] pair data structure to represent meshes. So it might create compatibility issues with efficient mesh libraries. But there are also some MATLAB implementations for mesh tools:
http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~rms/software/matlabmesh/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not sure those libraries can handle .UCD files. I could not find anything that informs that the libraries can do so. I'm just wondering if you are aware of libMesh. I read the libMesh documentation but I could any definitive answer on whether or not it supports the operations that I need it to support.

Comment: You can load these files using libMesh:
http://libmesh.github.io/doxygen/